# Weird errors in Xcode 7.3 while using Cocopoads

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

I get bunch od warnings but these errors are main problem:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FDataSnapshot", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.FDataSnapshot in MapVC.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Firebase", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.Firebase in DataService.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What's going on?

UPDATE:

So error pops out when I use simulator on my mac, but when I use my iPhone as simulator everything is fine. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1):

Okay this will maybe help someone so I'm posting an answer.

I noticed in my terminal
`Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.`
So that obviously messed up my code. Just delete Pods folder, workspaces and run `pod install`

Everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

could you not also run

```
pod update
```

then you dont have to delete the pod folder and workspaces..

Comment: I figured that simulator outputs linker errors but when I set my iPhone as "simulator" it works. Do you know what I have to edit to make it work on Simulator as well?